# Integrating MoPub SDK with Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, mopub

I am having trouble integrating MoPub SDK. I am following the documentation on twitter to download the android SDK, then editing the build path on my project's folder to incorporate it but I keep getting several build errors. I have android-support-v4.jar in a different folder but I've tried adding it as an external .jar but I get 2000+ errors. Even including the .jar's that are needed for the SDK (mopub volley support annotations, etc) doesn't help the build path.

[image]

Can anyone with experience help me with this issue?

Comment: @Nate do you have an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem adding third party libraries or even support libraries to `Eclipse` projects.

These libraries may come with resources or just .jar file.

**How to add with resources libraries:**

1. Create new `Android Project From Existing Code`
2. From project `Properties` > `Android` at the bottom check the `Is Library` CheckBox.
3. To add this library to your project > go to Project `Properties` > `Android` at the bottom `Add` to add library then choose the wanted library.

**How to add *.jar libraries:**

1. Create if not existed in your Project folder `libs` folder.
2. copy *.jar to `libs` folder
3. From Project `Properties` > `Java Build Bath` > `Add JARs` > choose the *.jar from your `libs` folder.

**EDIT:** I get to your question while trying to add `MoPub` library to my project and I got same errors.

Then after searching little deep .. I fix it and it is error free now.Here is the solution that works for me:

1. download these files required by `MoPub`: [mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/mopub/mopub-volley/com/mopub/volley/mopub-volley/1.1.0/mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar) and [Millennial Media SDK 6.1.zip](http://www.millennialmedia.com/sdk6)
2. Extract `Millennial Media SDK 6.1.zip` inside extracted folder you will find two folders open the one with the same name `Millennial Media SDK 6.1`... you will find two folders again open that one `mm-ad-sdk-android-6.1.0-5323db4` you will find a folder and two zip files extract that one `mm-ad-sdk-android-ant-6.1.0-5323db4.zip` with `ant` in the name.
3. Create a project from the extracted folder as I referred before in **How to add with resources libraries** you get `MMActivity` project.
4. From `file` tab > `Import` > `Existing projects into workspace` then choose `mopub-android-full-sdk.zip` you will get a project with some errors.
5. Copy `android-support-annotations.jar`, `android-support-v4.jar` and `mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar` to libs folder of `mopub-sdk` project.
6. Create a project from android-support-v7-recyclerview as referred before in **How to add with resources libraries** you will get recyclerview project.
7. From Project `Properties` > `Android` > `Add` .. add the MMActivity and recyclerview as 
   That works for me. I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution .... Fabric

To integrate with `Eclipse` [Eclipse plugin](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html)